# mvc-mini-profiler more than one EF context

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework-4.1, mvc-mini-profiler

I am using mini profiler on my project which has two EF contexts, SQL Server and Oracle.

I would like to only profile the SQL Server context.  How do I get mini profiler to exclude the Oracle context?

I currently get the following error for Oracle.

> The given assembly name or codebase was invalid. (Exception from
>   HRESULT: 0x80131047)